# jquery ui sortable modify html on creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i have a page with 2 elements:

1. a list of items with draggable method
2. a lost of items with sortable method

i only allow dragging from list 1 to list 2, and that seems to work ok.

now, what i'm looking for is that when i drag item from list 1 to list 2 the newly created element will contain some different html then the element that was dragged. is that possible?

iv'e tried this approach but that does not seem to do to the job:

```
    $("#list_2").sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        cursor: "move",
        delay: 150,
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        opacity: 0.5,
        scrollSpeed: 40,
        receive: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.item.html(ui.item.find(".hide").html());
}
});
        $("#list_1").disableSelection();
        $(".draggable").draggable({
        connectToSortable: "#template_parts",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid",
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
    }
            });
```

any help shall be greatly appriciated

Comment: Can you add your html or make a http://jsfiddle.net/ with an example?   Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jd8A7/

Comment: I can't get dragging from list 1 to list 2 to work in your fiddle.  Your calling draggable  on `.draggable` but I don't see anything with that class in your HTML..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var received = false;
$(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
        connectToSortable: "#list_2"
    });
    $( "#list_2" ).sortable({
        receive: function(event,ui){
            received = true;
        },
        stop: function(event,ui){
            if(received){ 
                ui.item.css('color','blue');
                ui.item.html(ui.item.html()+' changed');
                received = false;
            }
        }
   });
   $( "#list_2" ).disableSelection();
});
```

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/jd8A7/4/

Comment: @sd1sd1 please mark this answer as accepted it helped answer your question or give feedback.  Thanks

Comment: hello trevor. actually, this is not what i meant. 

i have an html elemnent inside the ui but calling  ui.item.html(ui.item.html().find(".div_name").html()); does not seem to work

Comment: i manageed to make my previous question work 

 stop: function(event,ui){
             if(received){ 
              htm = ui.item.find(".hide").html();
              ui.item.html(htm);
              received = false;
             }
            }